# Llamar a una función hijo desde el padre

Tags: angular

Tengo los siguientes ficheros

Padre.ts

```
@ViewChild(SumaComponent) private childrisk: SumaComponent;
test() {
  ....
  this.childrisk.suma()
}
```

Hijo.ts

```
suma() {
  console.log("sumando")
}
```

.html

```
    <app-suma #childrisk></app-suma>
    <button (click)="test()">Test</button>
    <button (click)="childrisk.suma()">Call</button>
```

Si hago click en "Test" no funciona, me dice childrisk is undefined pero si hago click en "Call" si llama a la función

Comment: No es una solución, pero y si haces `  <button (click)="test(childrisk)">Test</button>` y en TS `test(childrisk) { childrisk.suma()  }`, funciona?

Comment: si funciona, pero realmente no existe ningun boton, sino q llamo a un api y la respuesta llama a un método del hijo